# Accidently deleted files in cPanel home directory

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, file-manager, home-directory, public-html

I just wanted to delete the files under the public_html folder. But accidentally I deleted all the files under the home directory, like- etc, logs, mail, public_html, public_ftp, ssl, tmp, www. I have no backup. Now, I just created the public_html folder and put the WordPress files. When I browse the site, it says ---
"Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource. Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Could you please help me out? I'm so much confused.

Comment: Which user and group owns public_html

Answer (score 0):

if you are using shared hosting contact your hosting provider they might have a backup for your full /home directory and they can restore if from their end with the latest backup available.
if you are running a dedicated VPS I am not sure how it should be accessed